# Jquery post JSON to PHP

Tags: php, jquery, json

I'm trying to pass JSON data from jQuery to PHP so I can overwrite a JSON file. The problem I'm having is that I can't figure out how to tell if the PHP file is receiving my json that I am sending. I'm a bit of a novice..

I currently have this - it's not doing the trick and I'm a bit stuck. Any advice would be great. I am getting alert - 'Right' but nothing from PHP.

```
var testjson = [{
  "name": 1,
  "myArray": [{ 
    "0":"1",
    "2":"3"
  },{
    "1":"2",
    "3":"4"
  }],
  "friends":40  
}];

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "php/write.php",
  data: testjson,
  dataType: "html",
  contentType : 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
}).done(function(data, status) {
  alert('Right');
}).fail(function(data, status) {
  alert("Wrong: " + status);
});
```

```php
$value = json_decode($_POST);
print_r($value);
```

Comment: So, what do you get when you run your code? You need to tell us the issue.

Comment: try to  change this `dataType: "html",` to `dataType: 'json',`

Comment: @vietnguyen09 - That setting is for what the ajax request expects back. It has no effect on what it sends. In this situation, changing it to `json` would most likely just make jQuery throw a "parse error", since it doesn't actually return a json string.

Comment: So what's your problem?

Comment: Oh, you're setting "contentType". Remove that from your request and PHP will get the data correctly out of the box.  Then in your PHP, just do a `print_r($_POST)` (remove the `json_decode()`)

Comment: Sorry - the problem is, I'm not getting anythign back from my PHP - no 'print' or 'print_r' - just nothing (I've tried loading the PHP a different way and am having success)

Comment: How are you expecting to get the data back? In your code, you're not doing anything with the response, you're simply just alerting a fixed string. Try adding `console.log(data);` inside the `done()`-callback and _please_ update your question with a _proper and clear_ description of your problem.

Comment: Thanks Magnus, I updated the question.

Comment: Hi Magnus, I have added the console.log - I just get back the first alert I've added in which is 'print "PHP has been loaded";' - but I do not receive anything else - I would expect that '"print $value;" is not correct. How do I print the data that has been passed from jquery?

Comment: There is no mention of any string _"PHP has been loaded"_ in the above code. To see what the console outputs, open the developer console in your browser. You also need to add _all_ the relevant code + you need to give a _detailed_ explanation of what the issue is and _what you have tried_. This is Ajax & PHP 101. You should really start by reading a bunch of guides and tutorial. SO is _not_ a substitute for doing your own research.

Comment: I appreciate that Magnus, however I did do a lot of research. I thought my question was a simple one, apologies for upsetting you!

Answer (score 1):

Use the below code

```
var testjson =[{"name":1,"myArray":[{"0":"1","2":"3"},
            {"1":"2","3":"4"}],"friends":40}];

var myString = JSON.stringify(testjson);

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "write.php",
    data: myString,
    dataType: "html"
     }).done( function (data, status) {
    alert('Right');
})
.fail( function (data, status) {
    alert("Wrong: "+status);
});
});
```

And in php

```
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
print_r($json);
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it.

Knew it was super simple. Thanks for your help!

```
$value = $_POST;
print_r($value);
```